# Python Dash Plotly : Flip/reverse colour legend when formatting table

Tags: python, colors, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I want to colour a column by value with colour scale according to value high (in **Red** colour) to small (in **Green** colour).

However, by using the following code with default ‘**RdYlGn**’, I am only be able to do it in the opposite way, such as:
[image]

```
def discrete_background_color_bins(df, n_bins=7, columns='all'):

 bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins+1)]
 if columns == 'all':
     if 'id' in df:
         df_numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes('number').drop(['id'], axis=1)
     else:
         df_numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes('number')
 else:
     df_numeric_columns = df[columns]
 df_max = df_numeric_columns.max().max()
 df_min = df_numeric_columns.min().min()
 ranges = [
     ((df_max - df_min) * i) + df_min
     for i in bounds
 ]
 styles = []
 legend = []
 for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
     min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
     max_bound = ranges[i]
     backgroundColor = colorlover.scales[str(n_bins+4)]['div']['RdYlGn'][2:-2][i - 1]
     color = 'black'

     for column in df_numeric_columns:
         styles.append({
             'if': {
                 'filter_query': (
                     '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                     (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                 ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                 'column_id': column
             },
             'backgroundColor': backgroundColor,
             'color': color
         })
     legend.append(
         html.Div(style={'display': 'inline-block', 'width': '60px'}, children=[
             html.Div(
                 style={
                     'backgroundColor': backgroundColor,
                     'borderLeft': '1px rgb(50, 50, 50) solid',
                     'height': '10px'
                 }
             ),
             html.Small(round(min_bound, 2), style={'paddingLeft': '2px'})
         ])
     )

 return (styles, html.Div(legend, style={'padding': '5px 0 5px 0'}))
```

Can some one let me know how to highlight high values in **Red** and Small value in **Green** (or Blue) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be to reverse the list of colors.

So instead of this:

```
backgroundColor = colorlover.scales[str(n_bins+4)]['div']['RdYlGn'][2:-2][i - 1]
```

you could do this:

```
backgroundColor = colorlover.scales[str(n_bins+4)]['div']['RdYlGn'][::-1][2:-2][i - 1]
```

Comment: Thanks @Bas van der Linden ! It works like a charm!

I also tried a few other colour scales, such as 'YlOrRd', and 'Jet', but I got KeyError . Do you happen to know why ? Thanks.

Comment: @FlyUFalcon The `'YlOrRd'` color scale does not seem to be part of `'div'`, but instead of `'seq'`. See the source code [here](https://github.com/plotly/colorlover/blob/master/colorlover/__init__.py#L5). [`'Jet'` is a `plotly` colorscale](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/5e327e76e11c5e8a82d74d9d2ea0a44519a4b43e/packages/python/plotly/_plotly_utils/colors/__init__.py), but not a `colorlover` colorscale it seems.

Comment: I'm not sure why `'Jet'` and some other colorscales are part of plotly, but not part of  `colorlover`, but you could easily use your only list of rgb colors if the provided scales don't cut it.  For example:  `colorlover.scales['3']['seq']['YlOrRd']` = `['rgb(255,237,160)', 'rgb(254,178,76)', 'rgb(240,59,32)']`.

Comment: Thanks. I still haven't figured out how to customize color legend. Do you mind having a look on my latest question    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004814/python-dash-plotly-customise-colour-legend-when-formatting-table   ? Many Thanks.